# jQuery load() alternative

Tags: jquery

I use a script to include HTML bits from an external file using load().

```
$('#includeHTML').load('includeHTML.html #containerID');
```

If I decide to include these HTML div in the same file instead of external file, what should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#includeHTML').html($('#containerID').html());`

...but why is that even necessary? If you're going to put the snippets of HTML into the same file, put them where they belong. Then you won't have to use any JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe you want to add empty() before append in case there is some HTML already in #includeHTML

Comment: Wouldnt the html be overwritten regardless?

Comment: @Loktar: I think that Cybernate commented on my answer before I edited it.

Comment: I think I'm overthinking this... It should be as simple as pointing a div ID to the id of placeholder. @Matt Ball I'm changing what HTML goes where with form controls.

Comment: @santa: is there a question in your comment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `$('#containerID').clone().appendTo('$includeId')`